# Grouping Grouped results from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm a super duper newb with elasticsearch

I have a bunch of products on my elasticsearch. Each elasticsearch record has `title, pid, product_group, color, size, qty...` etc, many more fields

Now when I'm doing my request, what I want to happen is for it to group the results by pid, and then inside the `_group` part of the response, I also want those grouped as well, by `product_group`.

So in other words, if I have

```
pid: 1, product_group: 1, size: 1
pid: 1, product_group: 1, size: 2
pid: 1, product_group: 2, size: 1
pid: 1, product_group: 2, size: 2
pid: 2, product_group: 3, size: 1
pid: 2, product_group: 3, size: 2
pid: 2, product_group: 4, size: 1
pid: 2, product_group: 4, size: 2
```

I would want my top level search array to have 2 results: 1 for pid1 and 1 for pid2, and then inside of each of those results, inside the `_group` part of the json, I would expect 2 results each: pid1 would have a result for product_group 1 and product_group 2, and pid2 would have a _group result for product_group 3 and product_group 4.

Is this possible?

At the moment, this is how i'm modifying my query to group it based on pid:

`group: {field: "pid", collapse: true}`

I don't really know if I want collapse to be true or false, and I do'nt know how, or if it's even possible, to do a second layer of grouping like i'm asking for. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to go with child `terms` aggs:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_pid": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "pid"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_group": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "product_group"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "underlying_docs": {
              "top_hits": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the last `aggs` group is optional -- I've put it there in case you'd like to know which docs have been bucketized to which particular band.

Comment: Hmmm, i'm not having luck with that

Comment: I'm getting this `An unexpected error occurred: [400] Options contains invalid key: aggs`. I'll provide more context in a sec

Comment: I'm using this in my project: `import AppSearchAPIConnector from "@elastic/search-ui-app-search-connector"; const connector = new AppSearchAPIConnector({ 
    beforeSearchCall: (existingSearchOptions, next) => ` ... it's in here that i'm trying to add aggs to existingSearchOptions

Comment: What I provided is a standard search request that can be run with this curl: `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/your-index-name/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"size":0,"aggs":{"by_pid":{"terms":{"field":"pid"},"aggs":{"by_group":{"terms":{"field":"product_group"},"aggs":{"underlying_docs":{"top_hits":{}}}}}}}}'` I'm not familiar w/ that npm package.